# Running docker commands in bash script leads to segmentation fault

Tags: bash, docker, segmentation-fault

The commands are like:

docker run / stop / rm ...

which works in terminal while causes segmentation fault in bash script.

I compared the environments between bash script and terminal, as shown below.

```
    2c2
    < BASHOPTS=cmdhist:complete_fullquote:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
    ---
    > BASHOPTS=cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:login_shell:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
    7,8c7,8
    < BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
    < BASH_SOURCE=([0]="./devRun.sh")
    ---
    > BASH_LINENO=()
    > BASH_SOURCE=()
    10a11
    > COLUMNS=180
    14a16,18
    > HISTFILE=/home/me/.bash_history
    > HISTFILESIZE=500
    > HISTSIZE=500
    19a24
    > LINES=49
    22a28
    > MAILCHECK=60
    28c34,37
    < PPID=12558
    ---
    > PIPESTATUS=([0]="0")
    > PPID=12553
    > PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
    > PS2='> '
    32,33c41,42
    < SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
    < SHLVL=2
    ---
    > SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
    > SHLVL=1
    42,52c51
    < _=./devRun.sh
    < dao () 
    < { 
    <     echo "Dao";
    <     docker run -dti -v /tmp/projStatic:/var/projStatic -v ${PWD}:/home --restart always -p 50000:50000 --name projDev daocloud.io/silencej/python3-uwsgi-alpine-docker sh;
    <     echo "Dao ends."
    < }
    < docker () 
    < { 
    <     docker run -dti -v ${PWD}:/home --restart always -p 50000:50000 --name projDev owen263/python3-uwsgi-alpine-docker sh
    < }
    ---
    > _=/tmp/env.log
```

UPDATE:

The info and version:

```
docker version

Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3727
 Built:        Sun Feb 12 02:40:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3727
 Built:        Sun Feb 12 02:40:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

```
docker info

Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d
```

Comment: which docker image do you use? the "image description" is not present, by the way, add `docker version` and `docker info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've rewritten the docker command in a shell, it's entirely possible this is even a recursive definition. Remove this from your environment:

```
docker () 
{ 
    docker run -dti -v ${PWD}:/home --restart always -p 50000:50000 --name projDev owen263/python3-uwsgi-alpine-docker sh
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. @BMitch
I was too much concerned with Docker. And also tried to find the dumped core. Never thought it is because of the bash function name.